# How to assign a paragraph to a node correctly?

Tags: 9, migrations

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to link paragraphs to a content type in a newer version of Drupal. I have data from an older Drupal website that I need to migrate to a more updated Drupal version. I'm using the JSON:API to achieve this, but I'm encountering problems in associating paragraphs with a specific field in the content type.

Here's an overview of the process and the code involved:

1. I retrieve data from an older website's endpoint using JSON:API. The fetched data is stored in the currentData object, which contains both data and included arrays.
2. For each medical profile data fetched from the older site, I create a new node of the content type medical_profile in the newer site using the JSON:API.
3. Paragraphs are created and stored in an array called paragraphs.
   Each item in this array has the type and id of the paragraph.
4. Finally, I use the axios.patch method to update the node of the
   medical_profile content type and associate the created paragraphs
   with the field_conteudo field using the paragraphs array.

```
const createParagraphContent = async (id, medicalNid) => {
  const paragraphContent = currentData.included.find(element => element.id === id);

  const newParagraph = {
    type: 'paragraph--descricao_profissional',
    attributes: {
      field_label: paragraphContent.attributes['field_text_120'],
      field_texto: {
        value: paragraphContent.attributes['field_richtext']['value'],
        format: 'cohesion',
      },
      parent_id: medicalNid,
      parent_type: "node",
      parent_field_name: "field_conteudo",
    },
  };

  const axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      Authorization: authHeader,
    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.EQUALIZACAO_SITE_URL}/jsonapi/paragraph/descricao_profissional`, { data: newParagraph }, axiosConfig);
    return response.data.data.id
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao criar novo paragraph:', error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

The block bellow is the usage of this function

```
const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.EQUALIZACAO_SITE_URL}/jsonapi/node/medical_profile`, { data: newMedicalProfile }, axiosConfig);

      const paragraphs = [];
      for (let idx = 0; idx < element.relationships.field_label_input.data.length; idx++) {
        const elementTwo = element.relationships.field_label_input.data[idx];        
        paragraphs.push({
          type: 'paragraph--descricao_profissional',
          id: await createParagraphContent(elementTwo.id, response.data.data.attributes.drupal_internal__nid)
        })
      }

      const responseParagraphs = await axios.patch(`${process.env.EQUALIZACAO_SITE_URL}/jsonapi/node/medical_profile/${response.data.data.id}`, { data: {
        type: "node--medical_profile",
        id: response.data.data.id,
        relationships: {
          field_conteudo: {
            data: paragraphs
          }
        }
      } }, axiosConfig);
```

paragraphs array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    type: 'paragraph--descricao_profissional',
    id: 'fb01c352-2f1f-4a3f-b730-d8e298a2b271'
  }
]
```

Thank you for your time and assistance!

**@edit:** After receiving assistance from Giuseppe, I've made a few changes to my approach.

I've updated the createParagraphContent function to return the complete entity object instead of just the ID:

```
 try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.EQUALIZACAO_SITE_URL}/jsonapi/paragraph/descricao_profissional`, { data: newParagraph }, axiosConfig);
    return response.data.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao criar novo paragraph:', error);
    return error;
  }
```

And some changes at paragraphs loop:

```javascript
      const paragraphs = [];
      for (let idx = 0; idx < element.relationships.field_label_input.data.length; idx++) {
        const elementTwo = element.relationships.field_label_input.data[idx];
        const newParagraph = await createParagraphContent(elementTwo.id, response.data.data.attributes.drupal_internal__nid)
        paragraphs.push({
          type: 'paragraph--descricao_profissional',
          id: newParagraph.id,
          meta: {
            target_revision_id: newParagraph.attributes.drupal_internal__revision_id
          }
        })
      }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For entity reference revisions it's necessary to specify also the `target_revision_id`](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3092936#comment-14430274)

So, your paragraphs' array should be something like:

```
[
  {
    type: 'paragraph--descricao_profissional',
    id: 'fb01c352-2f1f-4a3f-b730-d8e298a2b271'
            "meta": {
              "target_revision_id": 120
            }
  }
]
```

By the way, be careful in case you PATCH paragraphs via JSON:API because the same applies, so you need to update the `target_revision_id` on the node, otherwise it will referer the "old" paragraph.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank for the help Giuseppe!